# Why doesn't asp.net make pagination efficiently on gridview controls?

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, gridview, linq-to-entities, pagination

I have a site with thousands of records and every time I make an action the gridview send around 300kb by ajax.
I try to make a custom pagination maintaining the ajax functionality, sorting, but it is so complicated.
I search for a hack to this but I don't find anything.

Links about:
http://www.nikhedonia.com/notebook/entry/efficient-paging-for-gridview/
http://kpumuk.info/asp-net/gridview-with-custom-digg-like-pager/

@mellamokb, this is the way I databind the gridview

CODE:

```
Dim res = From r In dc.Reservas _
    From u In dc.UsuariosData Where r.usr_Id = u.usr_Id _
    From c In dc.Campings Where c.camp_Id = r.camp_Id And r.sta_Id <> 2 _
    From rec In dc.OrdenesRegistros Where rec.rec_Id = r.rec_Id _
    From o In dc.Ordenes Where o.ord_Id = rec.ord_Id _
    From p In dc.Pagos Where p.pay_Id = o.pay_Id _
    From z In dc.Zonas Where z.zon_Id = r.zon_Id _
    Select New With {.res_Id = r.res_Id, _
        .usr_NickName = u.usr_NickName, .usr_Name = u.usr_Name, _
        .usr_LastName = u.usr_LastName, .usr_Email = u.usr_Email, _
        .usr_Cel = u.usr_Cel, .camp_Name = c.camp_Name, _
        .res_CreationDate = r.res_CreationDate, _
        .pay_Name = p.pay_Name, _
        .sta_Id = r.sta_Id, .camp_Id = c.camp_Id, .res_StartDate = r.res_StartDate, _
        .res_EndDate = r.res_EndDate, .zon_Id = z.zon_Id}

Session("datosGridView") = res
GridView_ZC.DataSource = Session("datosGridView")
GridView_ZC.DataBind()
```

Comment: Can you post a snippet of code demonstrating how you are databinding this `GridView`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pagination should be handled by the data source control.  If you are using a `LinqDataSource` control, then it should do the pagination with `AutoPage="true"` AFAIK.

**Edit**

Your data source has no pagination, so all of the data has to flow to the GridView before the GridView can paginate it.  Your LINQ-to-SQL  query returns all records.

You want to use a "smart" data source, like a `LinqDataSource` control.  The easiest way is to declare a `LinqDataSource`, bind the GridView to the data source in the markup, and then override the `Selecting` event of the `LinqDataSource` to specify your custom data retrieval logic:

```
<asp:LinqDataSource ID="MyDataSource" runat="server"
    OnSelecting="MyDataSource_Selecting" AutoPage="true" AutoSort="true">
</asp:LinqDataSource>

<asp:GridView ID="MyGridView" DataSourceID="MyDataSource" ... >
```

The code-behind:

```
Protected Sub MyDataSource_Selecting(sender As Object, _
        e As LinqDataSourceSelectingEventArgs)

    Dim dataContext As New MyDataContext
    e.Result = ' Put LINQ-to-SQL code here

End Sub
```

Comment: But, why the data source send and receive this amount of data? Is son inefficient to me. If I need to load 25rows, why send and receive 300KB on ajax update?

Answer (score 0):

Check this : http://www.seila.gov.kh/eang/ASPNET2.0/Web_2.0_With_ASP_NET_3.5.pdf
There a few chapters about optimization and perfomance, I recall reading something about gridview controls.